# Change metadata of pdf file with pypdf

Tags: pdf, metadata, pypdf

I'd like to create/modify the title of a pdf document using pypdf. It seems that the title is readonly. Is there a way to access this metadata r/w?

If answer positive, a piece of code would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

You can manipulate the title with pyPDF (sort of). I came across this post on the reportlab-users listing:

http://two.pairlist.net/pipermail/reportlab-users/2009-November/009033.html

> You can also use pypdf.
> https://pypi.org/project/pypdf/
>
> This won't let you edit the metadata
> per se, but will let you read one or
> more pdf file(s) and spit them back
> out, possibly with new metadata.

Here's the relevant code:

```
from pyPdf import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
from pyPdf.generic import NameObject, createStringObject

OUTPUT = 'output.pdf'
INPUTS = ['test1.pdf', 'test2.pdf', 'test3.pdf']

# There is no interface through pyPDF with which to set this other then getting
# your hands dirty like so:
infoDict = output._info.getObject()
infoDict.update({
    NameObject('/Title'): createStringObject(u'title'),
    NameObject('/Author'): createStringObject(u'author'),
    NameObject('/Subject'): createStringObject(u'subject'),
    NameObject('/Creator'): createStringObject(u'a script')
})

inputs = [PdfFileReader(i) for i in INPUTS]
for input in inputs:
    for page in range(input.getNumPages()):
        output.addPage(input.getPage(page))

outputStream = file(OUTPUT, 'wb')
output.write(outputStream)
outputStream.close()
```

Comment: When constructing a PdfFileReader, you need to pass a file-like object, not a string/filename (at least with pyPdf 1.13)

Comment: [PyPDF2](http://mstamy2.github.io/PyPDF2/) (which seems to have replaced pyPDF) has a native method that does this for you: `output.addMetadata({'/Title': 'title'})`