# Is there Python PDF metadata writing library for Windows?

Tags: python, pdf

Can someone point me to Python PDF package that can do metadata writing?
I found Python XMP Toolkit, but building Exempi on cygwin is nightmare I want to avoid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify pdf docinfo metadata, (not xmp metadata) in either of the following ways:

- [pdfrw](http://code.google.com/p/pdfrw/) seems to have some support for this (not a lot of documentation, but looking at the [alter.py](http://code.google.com/p/pdfrw/source/browse/trunk/examples/alter.py) example, it seems to be possible).
- This SO question uses [pyPdf](https://github.com/knowah/PyPDF2) library to make a new pdf with the desired metadata: [Change metadata of pdf file with pypdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2574676).

Alternatively, you could wrap a command line application like [pdftk](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) Tiny pdfrw package is perfect solution to my metadata problem

Comment: Pdftk is also docinfo only, not xmp.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to get a command line to modify metadata. Some tools modify both native and XMP metadata.

I wrote a blog on metadata editing a while ago: http://www.barcodeschool.com/2010/09/publishers-fix-the-metadata-in-the-pdf-file/