# Change metadata of pdf file with pypdf2

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf, pdf-manipulation

I want to add a metadata key-value pair to the metadata of a pdf file.

I found a several years old answer, but I think this is way to complicated. I guess there is an easier way today: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3257340/633961

I am not married with pypdf2, if there is an easier way, then I go this way?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do that using [pdfrw](https://github.com/pmaupin/pdfrw)

```
pip install pdfrw
```

Then run

```
from pdfrw import PdfReader, PdfWriter   
trailer = PdfReader("myfile.pdf")    
trailer.Info.WhoAmI = "Tarun Lalwani"    
PdfWriter("edited.pdf", trailer=trailer).write()
```

And then check the PDF Custom Properties

[image: EditedProperties]

Comment: Yes, it worked. In my case I needed to add a key which is not a valid python name, but it worked like this: `setattr(reader.Info, 'original-files', value)`. Thank you

Comment: Apparently using `pdfrw` results in the metadata being inaccessible using std methods. I don't have an Apple device to check custom metadata.

Answer (score 27):

I was surprised to see there is no code sample for [PyPDF2](https://pypdf2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/metadata.html) when the questions is explicitly asking for PyPDF2, so here it is:

```py
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter

reader = PdfFileReader("source.pdf")
writer = PdfFileWriter()

writer.appendPagesFromReader(reader)
metadata = reader.getDocumentInfo()
writer.addMetadata(metadata)

# Write your custom metadata here:
writer.addMetadata({"/Some": "Example"})

with open("result.pdf", "wb") as fp:
    writer.write(fp)
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. `appendPageFromReader` just adds the correct number of Blank pages.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. The metadata is transferred correctly to `writer` but `Some: Example` isn't added.

Answer (score 9):

## The correct way to edit PDF metadata in Python

There are several ways to edit PDF metadata in Python, but one way is better than the others.

I will start by talking about other ways that seem right but have side effects. Skip to the end of this article if you don’t have enough time and just use the correct way.

**Weakness is package not maintained.**

```py
from pdfrw import PdfReader, PdfWriter, PdfDict

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pdf_reader = PdfReader('old.pdf')
    metadata = PdfDict(Author='Someone', Title='PDF in Python')
    pdf_reader.Info.update(metadata)
    PdfWriter().write('new.pdf', pdf_reader)
```

> pdfrw can do quite easily without losing non-display information such as bookmarks.
>
> PyPDF2 supports more PDF features than pdfrw, including decryption and more types of decompression.

---

**Weakness is PDF not preserve outlines(bookmarks).**

```py
import pprint

from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter

if __name__ == '__main__':
    file_in = open('old.pdf', 'rb')
    pdf_reader = PdfFileReader(file_in)
    metadata = pdf_reader.getDocumentInfo()
    pprint.pprint(metadata)

    pdf_writer = PdfFileWriter()
    pdf_writer.appendPagesFromReader(pdf_reader)
    pdf_writer.addMetadata({
        '/Author': 'Someone',
        '/Title': 'PDF in Python'
    })
    file_out = open('new.pdf', 'wb')
    pdf_writer.write(file_out)

    file_in.close()
    file_out.close()
```

Using `PdfFileWriter` create a new PDF, and get old contents through `appendPagesFromReader()`, then `addMetadata()`.

It seems that we cannot directly modify the PDF metadata, so we add all pages and metadata then write out to a new file.

---

**The correct way to edit PDF metadata in Python.**

```py
import pprint

from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileMerger

if __name__ == '__main__':
    file_in = open('old.pdf', 'rb')
    pdf_reader = PdfFileReader(file_in)
    metadata = pdf_reader.getDocumentInfo()
    pprint.pprint(metadata)

    pdf_merger = PdfFileMerger()
    pdf_merger.append(file_in)
    pdf_merger.addMetadata({
        '/Author': 'Someone',
        '/Title': 'PDF in Python'
    })
    file_out = open('new.pdf', 'wb')
    pdf_merger.write(file_out)

    file_in.close()
    file_out.close()
```

Using `PdfFileMerger` concatenate pages through `append()`.

`append(fileobj, bookmark=None, pages=None, import_bookmarks=True)`

- **import_bookmarks** (bool) – You may prevent the source document’s bookmarks from being imported by specifying this as False.

### References

[pdfrw: the other Python PDF library](https://www.binpress.com/pdfrw-python-pdf-library/)
[Reading and writing pdf metadata](http://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/blog/2013/06/13/Reading-and-writing-pdf-metadata/)

Comment: When using pypdf2, my bookmarks becomes offset, and my toc looses all links.

Comment: I tested that correct way with a number of PDFs of different making (Acrobat, Libre etc.): In not one case did the output file contain the pdf's body content. It was empty. But even worse, the pdf_merger section destroyed the input file, leaving it as a 0 kb zombie.

Comment: I tried all several (or all) of these methods and found that the first (`pdfrw`) to be the one that works. It's fast and it even allows for the creation of custom metadata. You might need to watch the capitalization of `key` values.

Answer (score 8):

Building on what Cyril N. stated, the code works fine, but it creates a lot of "trash" files since now you have the original file *and* the file with the metadata.

I changed the code a bit since I will run this on hundreds of files a day, and don't want to deal with the additional clean-up:

```py
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter

reader = PdfFileReader("your_original.pdf")
writer = PdfFileWriter()

writer.appendPagesFromReader(reader)
metadata = reader.getDocumentInfo()
writer.addMetadata(metadata)

# Write your custom metadata here:
writer.addMetadata({"/Title": "this"})

with open("your_original.pdf", "ab") as fout:
    # ab is append binary; if you do wb, the file will append blank pages
    writer.write(fout)
```

If you do want to have it as a new file, just use a different name for the pdf in fout and keep ab. If you use wb, you will append blank pages equal to your original file.

Answer (score 4):

## Use pypdf (PyPDF2 is deprecated)

I'm the maintainer of both libraries.

Here is an example how to add metadata to a given document using pypdf:

```py
from pypdf import PdfWriter

writer = PdfWriter(clone_from="source.pdf")
writer.add_metadata(
    {
        "/Author": "Martin",
        "/Producer": "Libre Writer",
        "/Title": "Title",
        "/Subject": "Subject",
        "/Keywords": "Keywords",
        "/Creator": "Creator",
        "/CustomField": "CustomField",
    }
)

with open("result.pdf", "wb") as fp:
    writer.write(fp)
```

Answer (score -1):

With PyPDF 2 version greater than 3.0 :

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader,PdfWriter

def update_metadata_for_filename(filename, title, author):
    reader = PdfReader(filename)

    writer = PdfWriter()
    writer.append_pages_from_reader(reader)
    writer.metadata = reader.metadata
    
    # Add the metadata
    writer.add_metadata(
        {
            "/Author": author,
            "/Title": title
        }
    )

    # Save the new PDF to a file
    with open(filename, "wb") as f:
        writer.write(f)
```