# add custom metadata to pdf using python

Tags: python, pypdf, pdfrw

I want to add custom metadata to pdf file. This can be achieved by pypdf2 or pdrw library. I have referred [Change metadata of pdf file with pypdf2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46849733/change-metadata-of-pdf-file-with-pypdf2)
solution works fine, when there is no space between the two words of attribute.

In my case my metadata is like

```
meta = {'Page description' : 'description',
        'create time' : '123455' }
```

when I try to add above metadata as :

```
reader = PdfFileReader(filename)
writer = PdfFileWriter()
writer.appendPagesFromReader(reader)
writer.addMetadata(meta)
with open(filename, 'wb') as fout:
    writer.write(fout)
```

when we try to see the custom properties in document property of pdf,  nothing is displayed.

The above solution works fine if attributes are without spaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know about pypdfw, but for pdfrw, you should use PdfName('Page description') as your dictionary key.  This will properly encode the space.

Disclaimer:  I am the primary pdfrw author.

Comment: I tried this solution, but no success.. Just to confirm, here is my dictionary look like now:
```
meta = {'PdfName(Page description)': 'Description', 'PdfName(create time)': '12345'}
```

Comment: PdfName should not be inside the quotes.  It is a function inside pdfrw.  Also, you should consider using PdfDict instead of a real dict.  pdfrw works better when you use its primitives that map to PDF primitives.

Comment: The following code worked for me:

trailer = PdfReader(filename)
for k,v in dct.items():
        trailer.Info[pdfrw.objects.pdfname.PdfName(k)] = v
PdfWriter(filename, trailer=trailer).write()

Here dct = dictionary object
@Patrick Maupin : will try to use PdfDict as well.

Comment: when I am creating dictionary with PdfName, I am getting this error : Expected PDF /name object (line=14, col=14, token='00:00:00'). Can you help in this