# Add metadata to pdf using pypdf2

Tags: python, pdf, metadata

With the help of [Change metadata of pdf file with pypdf2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46849733/change-metadata-of-pdf-file-with-pypdf2) 
I worte the code below to add new metadata to a pdf-document. When running the code I get the error:

```
fin = open(file, 'rb')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'file'
```

I already tried to find the file with the package "os"- but same error
Want went wrong here? The file does exist...

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter

def editMeta(file, text):
    fin = open(file, 'rb')
    reader = PdfFileReader(fin)
    writer = PdfFileWriter()

    writer.appendPagesFromReader(reader)
    metadata = reader.getDocumentInfo()
    writer.addMetadata(metadata)

    writer.addMetadata({
        'comment': text
    })

    fout = open(file, 'ab') 
    writer.write(fout)

    fin.close()
    fout.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    file = 'Test_Angebot.pdf'
    editMeta('file', '#cool')
```

Comment: `editMeta(file, '#cool')` without quotes around `file`

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Thanks for this tip! Nevertheless the error changed to:`fin = open(file, 'rb')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Test_Angebot.pdf'`

Comment: It's probably that your file isn't in your working directory. Try giving the full path to the file instead.

Answer (score 2):

need to change `'comment'` to `'/comment'`.