# Writing pdf Metadata with r

Tags: r, pdf, pdftools

I would like to alter PDF Metadata with `R`. There are several questions relating to this topic. However, these solutions suggest using `pdftk` or `exiftool` which is not an option for me since I cannot download an exe-File to my machine. In addition, most questions are fairly old so I hope there may be a newer solution to my problem.

I tried relying on `pdftools` package which allowed me to access the metadata:

```
pdf_file <- file.path("c:/users/seb", "230307_0746_AEF.pdf")
info <- pdf_info(pdf_file)
```

The above code should work with any PDF (and indeed works for me). But: *I was not able to write the PDF* with the altered information. So here is my question:

1. Is there a way to write the PDF with the altered information with this package.
2. If not: Is there another way to alter the PDF-Metadata in `R`?

Comment: If you don't wanna use `exiftoolr` then consider python: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46849733/change-metadata-of-pdf-file-with-pypdf2

Comment: sorry, but neither python nor downloading an exe (which the package cannot cirmcumvent) is an option