# ReportLab - Metadata, CreationDate and ModificationDate

Tags: python-3.x, reportlab

How can I change metadata fields, `CreationDate` and `ModificationDate`, when I create a pdf with Reportlab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Take a look](https://bitbucket.org/rptlab/reportlab/src/c5d9818a4d549b358df080f288b902e728cb9f20/src/reportlab/pdfbase/pdfdoc.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#pdfdoc.py-1546) at where modification and creation dates are set:

```
D['ModDate'] = D["CreationDate"] = \
             Date(ts=document._timeStamp,dateFormatter=self._dateFormatter)
# ...
return PDFDictionary(D).format(document)
```

Basically, metadata is a dictionary saved at the end of binary string, start of string is file contents (`document`).

Inside Reportlab the workflow you ask about can be:

- create canvas
- draw something on it
- get `document` from canvas
- create `PDFDictionary` with artificial mod and create dates
- format document with `PDFDictionary`
- save to file

[Change metadata of pdf file with pypdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2574676/change-metadata-of-pdf-file-with-pypdf) also attempts similar goal.

Answer (score 0):

The ReportLab (currently 3.5) `Canvas` provides public methods, like  `Canvas.setAuthor()`, to set the `/Author`, `/Title`, and other metadata fields (called "Internal File Annotations" in the [docs](https://www.reportlab.com/docs/reportlab-userguide.pdf), section 4.5).

However, there is no method for overriding the `/CreationDate` or `/ModDate`.

If you only need to change the *formatting* of the dates, you can simply use the [Canvas.setDateFormatter()](https://hg.reportlab.com/hg-public/reportlab/file/61ba11e7d143/src/reportlab/pdfgen/canvas.py#l430) method.

The methods described above modify a `PDFInfo` object, as can be seen in the [source](https://hg.reportlab.com/hg-public/reportlab/file/61ba11e7d143/src/reportlab/pdfbase/pdfdoc.py#l1522), but this is part of a *private* `PDFDocument` (as in `Canvas._doc.info`).

If you really do need to override the dates, you could either hack into the private parts of the canvas, or just search the content of the resulting file object for `/CreationDate (...)` and `/ModDate (...)`, and replace the value between brackets.

Here's a quick-and-dirty example that does just that:

```
import io
import re
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas

# write a pdf in a file-like object
file_like_obj = io.BytesIO()
p = canvas.Canvas(file_like_obj)
# set some metadata
p.setAuthor('djvg')
# ... add some content here ...
p.save()

# replace the /CreationDate (similar for /ModDate )
pdf_bytes = file_like_obj.getvalue()
pdf_bytes = re.sub(b'/CreationDate (\w*)', b'/CreationDate (D:19700101010203+01)', pdf_bytes)

# write to actual file
with open('test.pdf', 'wb') as pdf:
    pdf.write(pdf_bytes)
```

The example above just illustrates the principle. Obviously one could use fancy regular expressions with lookaround etc.

From the pdf [spec](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf):

> Date  values  used  in  a  PDF  shall  conform  to  a  standard  date  format,  which  closely  follows  that  of  the  international standard ASN.1 (Abstract Syntax Notation One), defined in ISO/IEC 8824. A date shall be a text string of the form
>
> ( D : YYYYMMDDHHmmSSOHH' mm  )